# I'm getting a missing permission error because of the "server booster" role, How can I get him to take all roles except this role?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My code is like this:

```
let rMember = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get([0]));

let crewmate = message.guild.roles.cache.get("752639666393710614");

rMember.roles.set([crewmate]);
```

The code works correctly, but if the person has the role of "Server Booster", it gives a Missing Permission error.

How can I get him to take all roles except the "server booster" role?

Comment: check if your bot is higher on the role list then the server booster role and if not make sure that it is

Comment: I am authorized to take and grant the "Server Booster" role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem.
It doesn't give an error when I do it this way.

```
let rMember = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get([0]));


const crewmate = ["752639666393710614"];

if(rMember.roles.cache.has("server booster role id")) {
roles[1] = "server booster role id";
}

rMember.roles.set(crewmate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can assign/reassign booster roles or bot roles. You can prevent any errors coming from this by adding any [`managed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/reply-prefix/class/Role?scrollTo=managed) roles (roles you can't assign/reassign) to the array.

```js
let rMember = message.guild.member(
 message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get([0])
);

let crewmate = message.guild.roles.cache.get('752639666393710614');

rMember.roles.set([
 crewmate, // add the crewmate role
 ...rMember.roles.cache.filter((role) => role.managed).array(), // and any existing `managed` roles
]);
```

Comment: I get this error : `(node:11764) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
roles[1]: Value "{}" is not snowflake.`

Answer (score 0):

The role "Server Booster" can only be given when a user boost the server.

Good coding.